# Disable snapping on invisible layers when digitising

Tags: qgis

I would like to disable the snapping on invisible layers when digitising.
What I have done is to disable the command in the digitising settings but it doesn't work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked whether the hidden layer is listed in your [snapping tools](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html?highlight=tracing#index-1) `advanced configuration`? I suggest you switch to `all layers` and control the layers you want to snap to by turning them on and off.